# Hypothesis test: How to determine if the critical value of t should be positive or negative?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm doing hypothesis testing questions in my textbook and one of the things I'm not understanding is how to determine if the $t$ value I'm comparing to is supposed to be positive or negative.

The question I'm doing goes like this:

> In an experiment designed to measure the time
>   necessary for an inspector’s eyes to become used
>   to the reduced amount of light necessary for penetrant
>   inspection, the sample average time for
>   n = 9 inspectors was 6.32 s and the sample standard
>   deviation was 1.65 s. It has previously been
>   assumed that the average adaptation time was at
>   least 7 s. Assuming adaptation time to be normally
>   distributed, does the data contradict prior belief?
>   Use the t test with $\alpha = .1.$

So to do this I listed out all the values given:
$mean = 6.32, a = .1, n=9, s=1.65, H_0: μ = 7, H_a: μ < 7.$

So I subbed the values into this $t$ value equation:

$$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}.$$

and got the value of $-1.24$. I also looked up the other t value in the t table with $n-1=8$ and $\alpha =.1$, and got the value of 1.397. I thought we had enough evidence to question the initial hypothesis because the number I got is lower than the one from the table so it matches with the alternative hypothesis, but on the back of my textbook it says the correct answer is "Because $t= -1.24 > -1.397 = -t_.10,_8,$ we do not have evidence to question the prior belief."

My question is why do we not have enough evidence and how do I know whether I'm supposed to compare to a negative or a positive $t$ value from the table?

Comment: Hmmm so depending on the tail (i.e. Left, right or two tailed) this will change. So for a left tailed (<) you'll want to see if t is less than t*, for a right tailed (>) you'll want to see if t is greater than t*. Two tailed utilizes both t being less than the lower tail OR greater than the upper tail. I'm on mobile so I can't post an adequate answer but maybe this will help you

Comment: In addition for the lower tail (what your alternative states)  if t > t* then , the null hypothesis is not rejected.. Therefore if t < t*, the null hypothesis is rejected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start, let's dispense with some of the jargon, and introduce it gradually, as necessary.

Previously (before doing our experiment with the 9 inspectors), we thought
accommodation time was 7 sec. Now we have tested seven inspectors and they
averaged 6.32 sec. It would be foolish to think the sample average should
turn out to be *exactly* 7, because we know there is some random variation.
However, 6.32 does *seem* smaller than 7.00, and
we wonder if is *enough* smaller to indicate 7.00 is not right.

The amount of random variation can be expressed in terms of the SD 1.65
and the sample size. Specifically, $SD(\bar X) = 1.65/\sqrt{n}$ is called
the (estimated) 'standard error' of the mean.

As you say, the test statistic is
$$T= \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{6.32 - 7}{1.65/3} = -1.236.$$

Does the value of $T$ indicate that $\bar X =6.32$ is significantly smaller than 
$\mu_0 - 7?$

Notice that our comparison of $\bar X$ and $\mu_0$ has turned into a
comparison of $T = -1.236$ and $0$. If $T$ is more negative than
$t^* = - 1.397,$ the critical value of the test at the 10% level, then
we reject $H_0.$

Your printed table of Student's t distribution shows that 1.297 cuts 10% of the probability (area) from the upper tail of the distribution $T(df=8).$ But you are doing a 'left-sided' test ($H_a$ has a $<$ symbol), so you want to
cut 10% of the area from the *lower* tail of the distribution. Because
the distribution is symmetrical, that value is just $-1.297.$

In the figure below, the blue curve is the density function (PDF) of $T(8)$, the dotted red line is at the value you find in the
printed table (cutting 10% of the area from the upper tail of the distribution),
the solid red line is *your* critical value (cutting 10% from the *lower* tail),
and the thin black line is the observed value of the test statistic $T.$
The Rejection region is to the left of the solid red line, and the observed
value of $T$ is not quite negative enough reach the Rejection region.
So 6.32 is not enough smaller than 7 to be considered 'significantly smaller'
at the 10% level of significance.

[image]